# sql - add column with sum of another column to query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

i have a rather complex nested query that is structured like this:

```
select descr, sum(percentage) as perc from
( COMPLEX QUERY HERE)
as A group by descr  order by perc desc
```

thre result of this query is this:

```
descr                           perc
------------------------------------
bottom (1 * 18 cm²)             2.77
totalarea (1 * 70 cm²)          2.49
innerwalls (1 * 22 cm²)         2.37
bottom (2 * 12 cm²)             1.55
innerwalls (2 * 17 cm²)         1.51
risperror                       0.29
totalnumberdefects (1 * 30 cm²) 0.00
clipserror                      0.00
outerwalls (1 * 18 cm²)         0.00
outerwalls (2 * 16 cm²)         0.00
```

Now i would need to add a column, that contains the Sum() of perc, so in this case i would expect this as a result:

```
descr                           perc        sum
------------------------------------------------
bottom (1 * 18 cm²)             2.77       10.98
totalarea (1 * 70 cm²)          2.49       10.98
innerwalls (1 * 22 cm²)         2.37       10.98
bottom (2 * 12 cm²)             1.55       10.98
innerwalls (2 * 17 cm²)         1.51       10.98
risperror                       0.29       10.98
totalnumberdefects (1 * 30 cm²) 0.00       10.98
clipserror                      0.00       10.98
outerwalls (1 * 18 cm²)         0.00       10.98
outerwalls (2 * 16 cm²)         0.00       10.98
```

given that the query is really complex and slow, i would like to add the above column by starting by the result of the above query, without having to call the same query again for the results.

How can this be done?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I am using dbeaver 7.3.4 on a postre database

Comment: I'm not familiar with that DBMS. Does it support ANSI SQL? If so, I believe you could use a Common Table Expression to isolate the complex query, and derive both your `perc` and `total` columns from that.

Comment: You can read about CTEs [here](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/#:~:text=Introduction%20to%20Common%20Table%20Expressions,the%20ANSI%20SQL%2099%20specification), or I could write an example answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the SUM window function on your result:

```
WITH myquery AS (
  select descr, sum(percentage) as perc from
  ( COMPLEX QUERY HERE)
  as A group by descr  order by perc desc
)
SELECT *, SUM(perc) OVER () AS "sum"
FROM myquery
```

Comment: (A comment to the original poster, @sharkyenergy) This shows the use of a CTE, similar to what I would have done.

Comment: Thank you very much, never heared of the "over" statement. will have a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum()` with as window function:

```
SELECT *,SUM(perc) OVER (RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM (your_complex_sql_query) j
```

The frame `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` is optional in this case - as the frame has no order or partition -, but it is considered a good practice to make things explicit. So you may also just use `OVER ()`

```
SELECT *,SUM(perc) OVER ()
FROM (your_complex_sql_query) j
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=446aa37508eaf4d5f52369baae84ec70)

Answer (score 0):

Without using group by:

I used `window function sum()` to get the total perc and the total perc by descr.

```
SELECT DISTINCT descr,
       SUM(perc) OVER (PARTITION BY descr) AS perc,
       SUM(perc) OVER () AS "sum"
FROM (COMPLEX QUERY HERE) AS sq;
```

Or using `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (COMPLEX QUERY HERE)

SELECT DISTINCT descr,
       SUM(perc) OVER (PARTITION BY descr) AS perc,
       SUM(perc) OVER () AS "sum"
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Why are you using `DISTINCT`?  `SELECT descr, SUM(perc), SUM(SUM(perc)) OVER () FROM cte GROUP BY descr` seems to make much more sense?

Comment: Yes, it has, because I am not grouping by, so if you don't use `DISTINCT` you will not have a row by descr. You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c1fa0d9482fcdc16a2c2ad35d68e40e8)

Comment: I know it works, it's just a very peculiar pattern; you're creating duplicate rows then removing them, where as aggregates don't have that overhead.

Comment: No, I am not creating duplicate rows, rows are in the table (in complex_subquery) . This way I avoid the use of an additional subquery.

Comment: @MatBailie check accepted answer, he used one more subquery than I to  get the same result. It is a different approach.

Comment: Check the difference in explain plans... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ed61f0c0f8507c6c54c5c0461457316f

Comment: Yes @MatBailie, I had already checked it. I never say my query is the best option. It is an option (under certain criteria it is better and under others worse). it's good to have different options, because it allows you to choose; I think that is the goal of this website